# How to continue playing sound when holding key?

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I have a sound in JavaScript that plays when you press the up arrow key.
I would like to have the sound play when you hold the up arrow key, then pause when you release the key.

This is my code now:

```
var clickSound = new Audio("img/hartslag.mp3");

document.body.onkeyup = function (e){
if(e.keyCode == 38){
    clickSound.play();
}
}
```

Comment: It's kind of impossible to press a key up.

Comment: I suspect you mean "the up key", rather than "key up". Are you talking about an arrow key?

Comment: I mean the arrow key on your keyboard.....

Comment: I think you need to learn javascript before you can use it. Head over to http://CodeCademy.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play loop an audio clip on button hold up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405236/how-to-play-loop-an-audio-clip-on-button-hold-up)

Comment: @user3771096: hi this is the same question, like the one I answered. So you can delete the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to listen to 2 different events. Play on key down and pause on key up.

```
var clickSound = new Audio("img/hartslag.mp3");
var playing = false;
document.body.onkeydown = function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 38 && !playing){
        clickSound.play();
        playing=true;
    } }

document.body.onkeyup = function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        clickSound.pause();
        playing=false;
    } }
```

Code is not tested!

Comment: is there no possibility that you can pause the sound when you press again on key up?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Please clarify what you want to do or try my solution. 
You get events when: 1. key is pressed down 2. key is going up again after being presse. [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)