# How to play loop an audio clip on button hold up?

Tags: javascript, audio

I would like to have an audio sound plays when you hold the button up arrow key it wil loop my audio clip which is about 10 seconds long, but stops when the arrow key is not being pressed.... Here is my code now

```
var clickSound = new Audio("img/hartslag.mp3");

document.body.onkeyup = function (e){
if(e.keyCode == 38){
    clickSound.play();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two event listeners namely `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` to detect when the key is pressed and when it is released to play and pause/stop the audio respectively .

### Code

```
var clickSound = new Audio("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.ogg");

function playAudioOnKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    clickSound.play();
  }
}
document.onkeydown = playAudioOnKeyDown;


function pauseAudioOnKeyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    clickSound.pause();
  }
}
document.onkeyup = pauseAudioOnKeyUp;
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NygG7/1/)

Comment: is it not possible to play the sound as long as you hold arrow key up and pause when you release arrow key up. In case of pause it when you press arrow key down?

Comment: @user3771096: did you look at the jsfiddle link i provided? , the script does exactly as you asking for, i.e it will play the audio until you are holding the UP key and will pause it when you release it.

Comment: @user3771096: you are welcome :), we have to use this trick because sadly there is no such event is `onLongPress` or `onHold` in JavaScript :D .